# Correlation and Covariance of lognormal random variables

Tags: correlation, stochastic-calculus

Let $X_i$ be lognormally distributed stochastic variable and $j$ < $i$ then is this the correct formula to calculate their correlation (please specifically note the index of t):

$$ Correl(i,j) = Cov(i,j)/(\sqrt var(i) \sqrt var(j))$$

where

$$
Cov(i,j) = \frac{1}{t_j} \int_0^{t_j} <\frac{dX_i}{X_i}, \frac{dX_j}{X_j}>dt
$$

$$
var(i) = \frac{1}{t_i} \int_0^{t_i} <\frac{dX_i}{X_i}, \frac{dX_i}{X_i}>dt
$$

$$
var(j) = \frac{1}{t_j} \int_0^{t_j} <\frac{dX_j}{X_j}, \frac{dX_j}{X_j}>dt
$$

I have used angular brackets for quadratic variation.

Comment: Yes.${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @TheSimpliFire Thank you, I just wanted to make sure I was using the correct time indices. The covariance using t(j) and var(i) using t(i).